# how do I show just one item of my marionette collection and navigate between them

Tags: marionette, backbone-routing

I have a route

```
routes: { "pages/:id" :  "page"

         },
page: function (id) {                                                      
                    var pageView = new contentCollectionView({
                        collection: collection,
                        tagName: "div",
                        className: "pages"
                    });

                    pageView.close();
                    PAGE.content.show(pageView);

                },
```

However what I want to do is to only show the individual page in my collection that matches the id I am passing - I also want to be able to be navigate from that page to the preceding and next page in the collection.

So - how do I pass the identifier in to my pageView at the time of rendering so it only does the one item in the collection ( I believe I know how to get the item index in the collection as it loops through, but if you want to show an example of that as well it would be nice)

Answer (score 1):

According to your requirement i would recommend to render ItemView instead of CollectionView.
If you have CollectionView you have ItemView for sure :)
and pass special by ID model from you collection.

So you code may look like this:

```
page: function (id) {                                                      
    var pageView = new contentItemView({
        model: collection.get(id)
    });
    pageView.close();
    PAGE.content.show(pageView);
}
```

About navigation - you can check with **at** method index of model in collection to actualize navigation logic. If you also need to keep browser navigation(back and forward buttons) you have to checkout [Backbone.history](http://backbonejs.org/#History)

Comment: I don't see how that could work - the collection is an array of objects, inside of each object is a property pageid which is the id I need to get. So I figured I could use idAttribute: "pageid" on the model for my collection, but when I do collection.get(id) it is just returning an empty object.

Comment: No, collection its not an array - its object with methods and hash models - its an array. About  idAttribute - you are right - when you fetch you collection from backend you can use its id. + be sure that the param id is integer

Comment: ok I guess it was a cacheing issue - collection.get(id) is working with the idAttribute set.